# Data in the ResultSet ceases to exist when a getString is executed

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I am working on a small practice game that takes the names of the winner and loser and increments their records in a database. I'm using an access database. i have been able to successfully get data inserted into the database but have failed to build upon the name already there. the resultset shows the data that is needed but when i go to pull the data with a getString, the data disappears. here is a piece of the code.

```
public int getWins() {
    try {
        String StrWin = ult.getPlayerWin();
        rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT Name, Wins FROM t_Records;");


        while (rset.next()) {
            String DataWin = rset.getString("Name");

            if (StrWin == DataWin) {
                wins = rset.getInt("Wins");
                rset.close();
                return wins;
            }

        }
        rset.close();
        return -1;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    }
```

This code throws a no data found exception. Why does the data cease to exist when the getString has been executed?

Comment: I don't think you want to compare a String like this StrWin == DataWin.  Use .equals().

Comment: Try retrieving the column by index, or using `"name"` or `"NAME"`.

Comment: What do you mean "the data disappears"?

Comment: the error that gets thrown says no data found. but when i debug it, the data appears and then just vanishes and shows an exception. I'm am very confused by this and so are all my sergeants.

Comment: i am currently trying using an index instead of a string value. see if this works.

Comment: i have tried to use .equals and an index value for the column but im still getting the same result. here are some of the errors im getting 'java.sql.SQLException: No data found
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataString(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataString(Unknown Source)
 at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
 at AccessDatabaseConnection.getWins(AccessDatabaseConnection.java:112)
 at AccessDatabaseConnection.addData(AccessDatabaseConnection.java:41)'

Comment: i know that the resultset is successful in pulling the data from the table because it appears in the debug window with the value. but when i try to put that value into a variable the debug window no longer shows the value and instead shows an exception.

Comment: i seem to have found the solution to this very puzzling. the resultset.getstring value would null itself before i could put it's value into a variable. so i tried making a statement that would get the resultset.getstring value so statement.getResultset.getstring kept the value while resultset.getstring lost the value.